# Lotus note - Split .nsf file

Tags: lotus-notes

Is there anyone out there that has any experience in breaking up a lotus notes .nsf file into smaller chunks or can recommend a solution to do this?

I need to break the file down for processing with one of our e-discovery tools, but the program has file size limitations, so I will need to break the .nsf down into about 6 chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in MS Outlook, you cannot split your large NSF file into many small NSF files. You have to only repair it using some suitable software. For repairing your corrupt NSF file, you can try **Stellar Lotus Notes Recovery** Software which is an excellent software to repair corrupt NSF file and recovers all emails, calendar entries, notes, tasks, journals, attachments and address books. **Lotus Notes Recovery** software is an advanced and powerful tool which scans, repairs nsf files & performs quick recovery of corrupted NSF file components.

Comment: Actually, you can split MS Outlook PST files.  Although it is a manual process (1. Create new PST, grab folders from existing pst and drop into new pst, compact)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, splitting NSF file on binary level is bad idea. What you probably need is to split data inside the database into more new databases.
I would recommend to make an agent, which will copy documents into new databases. The key for split (and used as file name prefix/suffix) would be by year of date created, but it may be anything relevant to data you have - region, OU, close date...